# Saving illustrator file using applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm currently trying to automate a process whereby I take a .ai file, save it to the desktop, then change all the text to outlines and save another copy to the desktop with _OL added to the name, e.g.

```
IN> server/elements.ai
OUT> desktop/elements.ai & desktop/elements_OL.ai
```

Thanks to Tim Joe it now saves, but it won't select the text to convert it to outlines.

If someone could help me with this i'll be very grateful, I do this same process over and over again at work and having it automated would be the best.

Here's what I've got so far **(revised to include save options, illustrator version and file path as string)**:

```
 set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --place to save the files
set theFile to choose file --choose .ai file to get outlines on
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
set fullPath to (saveLocation & fileName) --file path of new .ai
set olPath to fullPath & "_OL.ai" --file path of new .ai with outlines


tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
activate
open theFile without dialogs
save current document in file fullPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save file to desktop
selectobjectsonactiveartboard --select all
convert to paths --convert all text to outlines
display dialog "pause"
save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save another copy to desktop with name + _OL.ai 
quit
end tell
```

Comment: what version of Ai are you coding against ?

Comment: It's Adobe Illustrator CS5.1

Comment: See my update. when working with alias, make them strings when changing them

Comment: Only issue I see above is Illustrator 15 needs to be after compatibility: inside the {}. You have it before. The save line should be as followed: "save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false}"

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's saving now, unfortunately now that it's saving I've learnt that it doesn't like the "select all" command -_-

Comment: Just tried using "selectobjectsonactiveartboard" instead but that doesn't work either

Comment: Fixed it. Look at my lasted update works 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Bottom for working Answer!

I always use save options so that could be the reason.

```
save theCurrentFile in file NewFileNamePath as as Illustrator ¬
                with options {class:Illustrator save options ¬
                , compatibility:Illustrator 15 ¬
                , font subset threshold:0.0 ¬
                , embed linked files:false ¬
                , save multiple art boards:false}
```

compatibility options: Illustrator 10 / Illustrator 11 / Illustrator 12 / Illustrator 13 / Illustrator 14 / Illustrator 15 / Illustrator 3 / Illustrator 8 / Illustrator 9 / Japanese 3 -- what Illustrator file format version to create ( default: Illustrator 15 )

Update: working save

```
set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --You were missing as string so it was making an array. The array adds "," making an invalid save location.
set theFile to choose file --choose .ai file to get outlines on
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
set fullPath to saveLocation & fileName --file path of new .ai
--set olPath to fullPath & "_OL.ai" --file path of new .ai with outlines

log fullPath
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    open theFile without dialogs
    save current document in file fullPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:false, save multiple artboards:false}

end tell
```

In short the two missing things:

- compatibility:Illustrator 15 --Must have a version number, you were
  missing it
- set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --    needs to be
  a string

enjoy :)

Update Use this:

```
    set saveLocation to ((path to desktop) as string) --place to save the files
set theFile to choose file --choose .ai file to get outlines on
tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of theFile
tell application "Finder" to set fileNameExention to name extension of theFile
set trimNumber to (((count fileNameExention) + 2) * -1) -- add two to include period and placment
set fileName to (characters 1 thru -4 of fileName) as string -- get just the file name with not extention
set fullPath to (saveLocation & fileName) --file path of new .ai
set VectorPath to fullPath & ".ai"
set olPath to fullPath & "_OL.ai" --file path of new .ai with outlines

tell application id "com.adobe.Illustrator"
    activate
    open theFile without dialogs
    save current document in file VectorPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save file to desktop
    convert to paths (every text frame of current document)
    display dialog "pause"
    save current document in file olPath as Illustrator with options {class:Illustrator save options, compatibility:Illustrator 15, font subset threshold:0.0, embed linked files:true, save multiple artboards:false} --save another copy to desktop with name + _OL.ai 
    quit
end tell
```

Done! Enjoy.

Comment: I gave it a try but now I'm getting the error "Can't make some data into the expected type"
I had to change your code slightly to make it compile and put the revised code in my question, have I written something wrong?

Comment: you need a compatibility version. Illustrator is invalid Illustrator 15 is valid. I will see if there is something else

Comment: I fixed the path so its a string, but after i've put the number 15 after illustrator I get "enumeration error". Also does 15 mean CS5?

Comment: Illustrator 15 is a illustrator term and can only be defined inside an illustrator tell block. Only way to get the enumeration error i can think of. Can you please post the latest version of your script. My last update was a tested and working but only did the first save of opening a file and saving it once.

Comment: I posted the latest version after my last comment. I'm not even sure what the illustrator 15 is doing, you said it's choosing which version of illustrator to save in, maybe I'm just being dumb but theres no CS15 for illustrator :/

Comment: It's adobe's back end code. 17=CC 16=CS6 15=CS5/CS5.5 and so on. Being that you are on CS5.1 you want 15. I am updating with what you need. Had some free time this morning.

Comment: No problem, don't forget about the bounty rep either. If not handed out it is lost.

Comment: oops thanks for reminding me, I'd give you extra bounty if I could as that has really helped me out, I'm coding like mad now modding this program to do all my work for me :p

Answer (score 1):

You can get just fullPath up to but not including the extension, and then add `_OL.ai` to the end of that:

```
set olPath to text 1 thru ((length of fullPath) - 3) of fullPath & "_OL.ai"
```

Comment: I had figured that part out since asking the question but thanks anyway :)  I don't suppose you might also know why the illustrator file isn't saving?